# Determine geograpic coordinates from one fixed location as accurately as possible without expensive hardware

Tags: gps, geolocation

I build a GPS disciplined oscillator and I need to set antenna coordinates in order to be able to operate it as accurately as possible.

What I need is a way to determine the geographic coordinates (in GPS reference frame) of a single fixed location (where the GPS antenna is placed).

This procedure will be done only once so:

1. no point in buying expensive hardware (although rent is an option).
2. hiring a professional to perform a single measurement, out of my budget.

Comment: Would a simple cellphone provide enough accuracy?

Comment: @DPSSpatial No. If it was the case, using the GPS module of the oscillator will be a simpler solution. Maybe averaging its output over a span of months can be enough. I don't know.

Comment: Could you use a well mapped feature, such as a survey mark? What sort of accuracy do you need?

Comment: @IanTurton The time accuracy I'm targeting is < 10 ns. I don't know how to translate it to space domain, but due to GPS working mechanism, as more accurate I know antenna position more accurate will be my clock signal.

Comment: @IanTurton I'm not aware of any survey mark near my place, but there is a cell phone antenna relatively close. If they are precisely geolocated and I have a way to access this info maybe I can use it in some way.

Comment: I doubt cellphone towers will be accurate enough

Comment: Depends on a country. In some city council has their assets, e.g. stormwater manholes published in web viewer. They usually well surveyed.